# How to space at end of program c++

Tags: c++, spacing, exit-code

```
"MATH IS FUN LETS..

A.  CALCULATE THE AREA OF A CIRCLE
B.  CALCULATE THE AREA OF A TRIANGLE
C.  CALCULATE THE VOLUME OF A CUBE

Enter A, B, C 
A

What is the radius?

5

Area of circle is:  78.5397Program ended with exit code: 0"
```

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEK3o.jpg)
The link to the code above.

I am using xcode to write this, how do i get that "Program ended with exit code: 0" to bump down to the next line?

Comment: See `std::cout << std::endl;`, for instance, but without code it is difficult to say.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do you notice how you managed to not have *all* the text on the same line? Why don't you use the same method as in the rest of the program?

Comment: Next time use http://pastebin.com/ to paste code, not just picture of it.

Comment: Why not embed the relevant code in your post? Many of us that might like to help are blocked from viewing internet file repo's by our corporate policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using streaming operators:

```
std::cout << "Area of circle is: " << circle_area << std::endl;
```

`std::endl` outputs a newline and flushes the stream (outputs the buffer).
If you don't want to flush (if the line is part of lots of output where not flushing is faster) then use this instead: `<< '\n'`

If for some reason you are using printf():

```
printf("Area of circle is: %f\n", circle_area);
```

`\n` is a newline symbol

Comment: And no, I can't follow your link. Embed the code in your question in future.